# How do I get the size of a file after ftp'ing?

Tags: c++, windows, ftp, wininet

```
CFtpFileFind finder(mConnection);
found = finder.FindFile("*.log");

   while (found)
   {
        found = finder.FindNextFile();

        wsprintf(fileInfo, "%s", finder.GetFileName());

        //need file size of this .log 
        //no member function for this in CFTPFileFind class?

    }
```

**EDIT**  Answer

finder.GetLength();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CFtpFileFind` seems to derive from `CFileFind` which has a `GetLengh()`.